# Hide the Yii Application Log (that shows queries etc..) - Yii 1.x

Tags: php, logging, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I am doing some work on a Yii 1.x project and would like to hide the 'Application Log' that appears at the bottom of the page with queries and other debugger stuff within it..

I have commented out the following 'log' array (in the components array) within my mode_gk.php file that I can see it relates to but it still shows all the logging? Can anyone suggest what I am missing?

```
        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                'web'=>array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'trace, info, error, warning, application',
                    'categories'=>'system.db.*',
                    'showInFireBug'=>false
                ),
                'file'=>array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning, watch',
                    'categories'=>'system.*',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

Comment: You just need to comment out the 'web' array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commented out the 'web' array as stated.